# Web Workers: SetInterval and SetTimeout reliability

Tags: javascript, timeout, html5-audio, web-worker

In a browser environment, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` aren't reliable for accuracy - where time sensitivity is an issue.

Recently, we've been given `requestAnimationFrame`, which allows us to do a little better (in terms of `performance.now()` and its timestamps).

Long story short - I decided to build a metronome in Javascript, and while it works, it's fairly inaccurate above a certain tempo. While compensating for late frames allows the tempo not to desync over time, the individual beats are slightly off, which doesn't work for a metronome. (This is not a problem for animation, as it by nature doesn't need to be discrete.)

Right now, I have the option of attempting to perform a lookahead based on a threshold that I specify, to attempt to place the click between available frames (using `setTimeout` in the animation loop). I imagine, though, that I'll run into similar problems as `setTimeout` isn't reliable in the browser due to the event loop, unless the HTML5 Audio API will allow you to delay playback by a number of milliseconds.

My question: Are `setTimeout` and `setInterval` more accurate and reliable in a web worker vs the browser environment?

Comment: The only way you'll get perfect timing is to use the audio api. There's a section on timing in [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) under "Dealing with time: playing sounds with rhythm"

Comment: @spender Hey, just wanted to say that webAudio actually worked like a charm (after jumping through some hoops for an infinite metronome loop). Good call, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can say 'yes' for your question, Web workers are reliable for settimeout and setinterval functions,because web workers runs on background according to ui,  so they provide you non-blocking ui events(they might affect metronome tempo), while you are processing the continuing metronome timing.

By the way there is a good doc about web workers in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).